# Warning came into angular and Laravel 5.2

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

This Warning is generated by angular js and AJAX to laravel 5.2:

> **Deprecated**:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead. in **Unknown** on line **0** 
>  **Warning**:  Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent in **Unknown** on line **0**

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You are triggering an `E_DEPRECATED` level warning (by using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`) which in turn is sending output (the error message) which prevents you from sending further headers. Fix the first error and the rest will go away

Comment: @Phil - that's a sort of non-answer (which is presumably why you made a comment).  This is an odd issue of PHP 5.6, and Angular - by default - sends AJAX requests in a manner that triggers this behavior.  Do you know of a **solution** to the Angular behavior that triggers this?